# run time text boxs

Tags: c#

hey all...
its very hard to explan  i hope you understand it and help coz i really need your help guys
the thing is i have to make the user choose the number of matrix with this number i have to create the same number of matrices again and do calculation on each one 
like if user matrix 3x3 i have to redo this matrix with different value 3 times
my question is :
1- how can i re do the same number of textboxs over and over .
2- how i can calculate each matrix and get the value
i hope you understand

Comment: Do you mean to say that you would like to create textboxes dynamically?

Comment: you want to create matrix dynamically and probably replicate the same 2 more time ? can you depict what u intend with an example

Comment: You really need to say what sort of app this is, too - web forms, MVC, WinForms, WPF, Silverlight?

Answer (score 1):

To create a `TextBox` dynamically, just new up a new instance of a `TextBox`, set the properties to decide where it should be shown, and add it to the `Controls` collection of the container where you want to place it.

As well as adding them to the `Controls` collection, you could also add the reference to your own collection, which could be, for example a list of lists. That way, when you need to do the calculation you'd just loop through that collection and get the values from each `TextBox`.

Comment: nice but how i can make it repeated by it self

Comment: @user: Not sure what you mean by repeated by itself so I might be answering the wrong thing now... Just put the code to create the buttons in a method of some kind and if you need to create another matrix you just call the method again. You could then also add event handlers to the textboxes so that when all 9 textboxes have been filled in, the event handler will automatically create 9 more textboxes. Is that anything close to what you're asking for?